# Magento 2 - How to resize image using image's url?

Tags: magento2, image, gallery-image

How is the right way of resizing images in Magento 2.

```
$image->getData('url');
```

I have the url of the image, how to resize it using the url? Is there an API / helper that does that?

Answer (score 0):

This should help you if you have `$_product` object:

```
$_imagehelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
$image = 'category_page_grid'; //from theme's etc/view.xml
//if you want aspect ration
//$aspect_ratio = true; $image_width = 200, $image_height = 300;
if($aspect_ratio) {
    $productImage = $_imagehelper->init($_product, $image)->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize($image_width);
} else {
    $productImage = $_imagehelper->init($_product, $image)->resize($image_width, $image_height);
    $productImageUrl = $productImage->getUrl();
}
```

If you have just got `URL` then using img style would be enough:

```
<img src="<?= $img->getData('url');?>" width="200"/>
```

Comment: I have the image URL and because I want to resize my gallery images and not just one product image. is there any way to do that?

Comment: use the second method from my answers.